# QOpenGLWidget optimal texture buffer allocation

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

My question is possiibly not related with Qt and/or QOpenGLWidget itself, but rather with OpenGL buffers in general. Anyway, I'm trying to implement a crossplatform renderer of YUV video frames, which requires converting YUV to RGB and rendering the result on a widget afterwards.

So far, I succeeded in the following:

1. Found two proper shaders (1 fragment & 1 vertex) to improve YUV 2 RGB conversion (Our project supports only Qt 5.6 so far, no better way for me to do it)
2. Used QOpenGLWidget to obtain a properly-behaving widget
3. Did my best with QOpenGLTexture to make the drawing

[Here](https://github.com/MasterAler/SampleYUVRenderer/blob/master/OpenGLDisplay.cpp) is my very sketchy code, which displays video frames from a raw YUV file and most of the job is done by GPU. I would be happy if it were not for the trouble of buffer allocations. The point is, frames are received from some legacy code, which provides me with custom wrappers around something like `unsigned char *data`, that is why I have to copy it like this:

```
//-----------------------------------------
GLvoid*                 mBufYuv; // buffer somewhere
int                     mFrameSize; 
//-------------------------
void OpenGLDisplay::DisplayVideoFrame(unsigned char *data, int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
{
    impl->mVideoW = frameWidth;
    impl->mVideoH = frameHeight;
    memcpy(impl->mBufYuv, data, impl->mFrameSize);
    update();
}
```

While testing the concept, frame and buffer sizes were hardcoded like:

```
// Called from the outside, assuming video frame height/width are constant
void OpenGLDisplay::InitDrawBuffer(unsigned bsize)
{
    impl->mFrameSize = bsize;
    impl->mBufYuv = new unsigned char[bsize];
}
```

Qt texture classes served well for the pupose, so...

```
// Create y, u, v texture objects respectively    
impl->mTextureY = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
impl->mTextureU = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
impl->mTextureV = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
impl->mTextureY->create();
impl->mTextureU->create();
impl->mTextureV->create();

// Get the texture index value of the return y component
impl->id_y = impl->mTextureY->textureId();
// Get the texture index value of the returned u component
impl->id_u = impl->mTextureU->textureId();
// Get the texture index value of the returned v component
impl->id_v = impl->mTextureV->textureId();
```

And after all the rendering itself looks like:

```
void OpenGLDisplay::paintGL()
{
    // Load y data texture
    // Activate the texture unit GL_TEXTURE0
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    // Use the texture generated from y to generate texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, impl->id_y);
    // Use the memory mBufYuv data to create a real y data texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, impl->mVideoW, impl->mVideoH, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, impl->mBufYuv);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // Load u data texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);//Activate texture unit GL_TEXTURE1
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, impl->id_u);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, impl->mVideoW/2, impl->mVideoH/2
                 , 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (char*)impl->mBufYuv + impl->mVideoW * impl->mVideoH);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // Load v data texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);//Activate texture unit GL_TEXTURE2
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, impl->id_v);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, impl->mVideoW / 2, impl->mVideoH / 2
                 , 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (char*)impl->mBufYuv + impl->mVideoW * impl->mVideoH * 5/4);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // Specify y texture to use the new value can only use 0, 1, 2, etc. to represent
    // the index of the texture unit, this is the place where opengl is not humanized
    //0 corresponds to the texture unit GL_TEXTURE0 1 corresponds to the
    // texture unit GL_TEXTURE1 2 corresponds to the texture unit GL_TEXTURE2
    glUniform1i(impl->textureUniformY, 0);
    // Specify the u texture to use the new value
    glUniform1i(impl->textureUniformU, 1);
    // Specify v texture to use the new value
    glUniform1i(impl->textureUniformV, 2);
    // Use the vertex array way to draw graphics
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

---

As I've mentioned above, it works fine, but it's only a demo sketch, the goal was to implement *generic* video renderer, which means aspect ratio, resolution and frame fize may change dynamically; thus, the buffer (`GLvoid* mBufYuv;` in the code above) has to be reallocated and, even worse, I'll have to memcpy data to it 25 times per second. Looks definitely like something, that wouldn't work way too fast with Full HD video, for example.

Of course, several trivial optimizations are possible, leading to reduction of data copying, but Google told me that there are different ways to allocate buffers in OpenGL directly, those PBO/PUBO things and QOpenGLBuffer at least.

Now, there is a problem -- I'm quite confused with all those many ways to handle textures and don't know neither the best/optimal, nor the one best fitting my case.

Any piece of advice is appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to reallocate the buffer at all. Allocate it once, and only grow it if needed, but there's no need to shrink it. Copying the data into the buffer is of no consequence (measure it and you'll see for yourself), but certainly you may wish to get rid of that premature pessimization, as it may be.